# CodeTemplate em .net core [scaffolding]

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

**Como em .net core 2.0 faço para criar os templates custom do scaffolding?**

No sistema antigo .net 4.6 copiava a pasta CodeTemplates para o projeto.

No .net core < 2 instavala o

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc
```

Depois acessava a pasta:

```
C:\Users\{User}\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc\1.0.0-preview2-final\Templates
```

Copiava a pasta para o projeto e funcionava.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas e agora com o .net 2.0? ao instalar o 
`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.0` e 
`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools 2.0` nada acontece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu realizei o download manual do pacote através do link.:

[**NuGet Gallery - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc**](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc/2.0.0)

Ao extrair o conteúdo do pacote, verifiquei que a pasta `Templates` estava lá com os seus respectivos arquivos.

Comment: executei via console foi, depois testei via visual studio foi, ou o console 'desentupiu' ou o nuget estava com problema desde domingo para esse pacote e agora voltou a funcionar